# App run only on xxHDPI displays on other crashed

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash, classnotfoundexception, crash-reports

Hello I have problem with my app.

I try launch it on HDPI phone but app crash while opening, and I don't know why. 
I don't know where i try find problem and I don't know how need paste here. please write what need paste.

Here are Errors

```
 06-30 11:34:27.432 6354-6354/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzan
06-30 11:34:27.456 6354-6354/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpv.zzg
06-30 11:34:27.484 6354-6354/sk.atest.paradox02.animacia A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                                        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4560)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.FlagProviderImpl.getBooleanFlagValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsf.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsd.get(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058) 
                                                                            at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4560) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
06-30 11:34:27.492 6354-6367/sk.atest.paradox02.animacia E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor
06-30 11:34:27.564 6354-6354/sk.atest.paradox02.animacia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{sk.atest.paradox02.animacia/sk.atest.paradox02.animacia.Index}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sk.atest.paradox02.animacia.Index
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sk.atest.paradox02.animacia.Index
                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: its not nullpointerExc... because on xxhdpi run good, and it's in class which not mine

Comment: this does not look like a DPI display problem. it is a coincidence I think.

Comment: And how solve it?

Comment: `its not nullpointerExc` so what do you call this? `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`. Moreover, you also have a `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: I see, but I don't know how solve it, because it's not in mine class.

Comment: I trying solve own and I know so problematics it's this 
        multiDexEnabled true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this into your manifest

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```